# Hide the element, but show for that place blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

could any body explain what I should modify, how after hiding the image, still keep the div as a blank with no content but the same width and height as it were with image,

**Exact example: http://jsfiddle.net/rJuWL/1/**

So after hiding, Second! comes to First!, 
but I need to keep it as
First! 
blank
Second!

Html

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>First!</div>
<div class="loading">
<img id="loading" src="http://preloaders.net/preloaders/284/preview.gif" class="none"/>
    <div>Second!</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Css

```
.none{display:none}
.loading{width: 32px;height:32px;}
```

Javascript

```
showLoading();    
function showLoading() {
  $("#loading").hide();
  $("#loading").show().delay(2500).fadeOut('10');
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dont hide it with `display:none`, set `visibility:hidden`

`display:none` will take it out of the DOM flow. Changing the `visibility` to `hidden` will keep it there but emulate setting `opacity` to 0.

Here's a quick demo which keeps your `fadeOut` http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/5cwE7/

Answer (score 1):

I would use opacity.

```
showLoading();    
function showLoading() {
  $("#loading").fadeTo(0,0);
  $("#loading").fadeTo(0,1).delay(2500).fadeTo(10,0);
}
```

The first `0` is the duration, the second is the opacity. `1` for show, `0` for hide.

However, your code doesn't really make sense. Why are you hiding it and then instantly showing it, then waiting 2 and a half seconds and hiding it?

I don't think the initial hide is needed (the first line of the `showLoading()` function in my code)

Edit:

Alternatively, you could use `.css("opacity",0)` in place of `.fadeTo(0,0)`, it is more than likely more efficient.

Comment: It's just a sample of the code, that's why it make no sense. I'll explain for what it needed, I've a web page, it loads up, and how some function, which is using ajax, so while sending ajax queries to server, the page is showing loading image ( showloading() ) and hides it after some time , that's it!

Comment: And, the initial hide, was used, if other ajax querie is started, so making sure the loading image would be hidden if it's already showing. Thank you so much.